# Decode the name or namespace from a UUID

Tags: uuid

Is it possible to decode the namespace or the name from a given UUID?

My idea is to generate the uuid with a particular namespace or name later and later retrieve it to check whether 2 UUIDs belong to the same namespace or name. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [RFC4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122), `UUID3` and `UUID5` namespaces and names are *hashed* (with either [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) or [SHA1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1)), which means there is no other way to “decode” the namespace or name from a given UUID than bruteforce (that is the whole point of [hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)).

> Compute the hash of the name space ID concatenated with the name.

[RFC422 - 4.3 - Algorithm for Creating a Name-Based UUID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.3)

However you can directly compare the hashed namespaces and name to detect whether two UUIDs belong to the same namespace *and* have the same name, indeed. Here is an example in Python (using the standard [`uuid`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) module):

```python
import uuid

name = 'stackoverflow.com'

a = uuid.uuid5(namespace=uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, name=name)
b = uuid.uuid5(namespace=uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, name=name)
assert a == b

print(a)
print(b)
```

```
cd84c40a-6019-50c7-87f7-178668ab9c8b
cd84c40a-6019-50c7-87f7-178668ab9c8b
```